# how to convert "0xbff18c08" to 0xbff18c08 int?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I am looking for an native function from the C libraries or code example to implement it: I have a string that contains byte values that I want to convert it to int value. how do I this? I tried using `atoi()` and `atol()` but it get only `0` from `0xbff18c08`. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean: "I have a char **array** that contains ..."?

Comment: @Jesper: I edited it to `string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you are likely looking for `strtoul(str, NULL, 16)`.

Answer (score 1):

The wording on your question is kind of strange.  Do you have a string?

You can check into sscanf:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/